# Why an AWS state machine does not display an execution as "timed out", but as "failed"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

We created a minimal state machine with a single AWS Lambda step. Then set the time out period of the step in the state machine descriptor to a low value.

It is correctly terminated with time out, but then the result is "failure" instead of "time out". I wonder why?

### Steps to reproduce

1. Create a simple Lambda function which will make a long running process. To keep it simple, create a Python script and make the function sleep for some seconds:

   ```
   import time

   def lambda_handler(event, context):
       time.sleep(10)   # Delays for 10 seconds.
       return event
   ```
2. Set the timeout for the Lambda function to 30 sec. (It will never actually time out.)
3. Create a simple State Machine which will invoke this Lambda with a timeout of 5 seconds:

   ```
   {
       "StartAt": "Execute Lambda",
       "States" : {
          "Execute Lambda" : {
              "Type" : "Task", 
              "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:**********:function:helloWorld",
              "TimeoutSeconds" : 5, 
              "Retry": [
                  {
                       "ErrorEquals": ["States.ALL"],
                       "MaxAttempts": 0
                  }
               ],
               "End" : true
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Start an execution.

### Result

According to the "Execution event history", the last event is "ExecutionFailed" and "error" is "States.Timeout". So far, so good.

But:

1. When you view the list of the executions of the state machine, the status of this execution is "Failed". (Expected: "Timed out".)
2. When you view the list of the state machines, this execution increases the counter in the "Failed" column. (Expected: increase the counter in the "Timed out" column.)

I'd guess that somehow the execution result is not correctly "mapped", but can't find the reason why. Or, it is just a bug in Lambda-based State Machine steps?!

Answer (score 0):

There are five status associated to a State Machine execution.

- Running
- Succeeded
- Failed
- Aborted
- Timed out

An execution can run for up to 1 year. If one of the states in the state machine execution is timed out then execution is failed not timed out. However if execution is running for more than 1 year you would see the status 'Timed out'.

See step functions [limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html).

> If an execution runs for more than the 1 year limit, it will fail with
>   a States.Timeout error and emit a ExecutionsTimedout CloudWatch
>   metric.

Answer (score 0):

The Timed Out status in Step Function is only for the execution time of the Step Function (until 1 year), the time out state of your lambda function is a Failed event for the State. Remember that you can create an state "Type": "Wait" in your step machine, this way you save time running lambda that is billable.